# how to find the correct orientation of the normal vector of a surface integral (inward vs outward)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am studying vector calculus and we are doing surface integrals.  when doing the cross product of the surface parameters, how do you determine whether you have the outward or the inward normal vector?

for example, I know that, for a sphere, I do (r of phi) cross (r of theta), and not (r of theta) cross (r of phi), since it is given in the textbook.  But if I have a parametric equation of an unknown shape (on a test, without graphing tool), how do I know the order of the cross product, thus, whether a given cross product points outward or inward?

Comment: Try pluggin some points of the surface into the cross product that you got and see where it goes to. this may help http://math.bard.edu/~mbelk/math601/SurfaceIntegrals.pdf

Comment: As with so many things in calculus, start by drawing a picture. Mentally applying the left-hand rule to such a picture will help you figure it out.